# How does uniqueness of the additive inverse imply that $-(ax) = (-a)x$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, ring-theory

> How does uniqueness of the additive inverse imply that $-(ax) = (-a)x$?

In my title, I should be clear that the **additive inverse** should be unique. But how does this help?
I dont even get why uniqueness of a negative number matters... Is there a third class of numbers I should know about?

Comment: Made a mistake, ax should be (-a)x.  I changed it

Comment: That makes more sense.

Comment: I can't award two answers... and I dont know who to give it to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(-a)x + ax = (-a + a)x = 0x = 0,$$ so $(-a)x$ is an additive inverse of $ax$.

Now by the uniqueness of the additive inverse, $(-a)x = -(ax)$.

Comment: Thats very clear, thank you

Comment: @SwagmcMuffin You're welcome. Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use distributivity to show that $ax+(-(ax))=0$, then apply uniqueness.

Comment: I hope im doing this right: let me add more info, (I pressed enter unknowingly) 

Got to the point (a + -a) x = 0,

ax + (-a)x = 0.   SO because the additive inverse is unique, then (-a)x = -(ax) because something has to fill in the variable satisfying ax + y = 0.  Thanks